# Как настроить vue в django?

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, webpack, vue.js

Пытаюсь настроить vue в django. Прошерстил все что только возможно но нормального полноценного гайда не нашел. Пытаюсь по крупицам запустить
package.json

```
{
  "name": "vuewebpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack main.js build.js"
  },
  "author": "yaroslav baev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "vue": "^2.2.6",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^11.3.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.6",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
// var Vue = require('vue')
// var hello = require('vue!../components/hello.vue')
import Vue from 'vue'
import hello from './components/hello.vue'

Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.delimiters = ['[[', ']]'];
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        hello: { hello }
    }
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports={
entry:'./main.js',

output:{
    path:__dirname,
    filename:'build.js'
},

module:{
    loaders:[
        {test:/.vue$/, loader:'vue-loader'},
        {test:/\.js$/, loader:'babel-loader', exclude:/node_modules/}
    ]
}};
```

hello.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>[[ greeting ]]</h1>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {
                greeting: 'Привет Webpack'
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    <script src="{% static 'build.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <hello></hello>

</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите, что у меня не правильно и что мне надо исправить?

Comment: А вы сделали сборку файла командой webpack (или как вы настроили там...)? Все прошло нормально в консоле?

Comment: да, все прошло нормально

Comment: Вы не описали саму суть возникшей проблемы, в чем она? Может ошибки в консоли? Как минимум, предупреждение точно должно быть, потому что вы монтируете к `body`.

Answer (score -1):

Вы подключаете файл vue в django файле, а именно - Views.py from django import loader
from django import render
def index(request):
 return render(request, "index.html")
В самом индекс нужно писать vue

Comment: index.html  а не index.vue! Главная страница рендерится джангой, а вот то что внуутри body уже должно подтягиваться с помощью vue

Comment: Ах, да нужно в html файл, и чтобы в нем был vue

Comment: Нужно просто изменить index.vue на index.html, а html файле все, что нужно